# Python Error " <method> missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' "

Tags: python, abstraction

New to Python.  Trying to create a simple example that demonstrates abstraction to 2 levels.
Getting an error   TypeError: 'HPNotebook' object is not callable "

I've looked through tons of examples and am still stumped.

To understand I have shown the 3 levels in the code.
Can you point me to someplace that helps explain this problem and how to eliminate it or 
offer a suggestion as to how to correct this.
Thanks

```
from abc import abstractmethod,ABC   #this is to allow abstraction. the ABC forces inherited classes to implement the abstracted methods.

class TouchScreenLaptop(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod      #indicates the following method is an abstract method.
    def scroll(self):    # a function within the parent
        pass             #specifically indicates this is not being defined
    @abstractmethod      #indicates the following method is an abstract method.
    def click(self):    
        pass             #specifically indicates this is not being defined

class HP(TouchScreenLaptop):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod         #indicates the following method is an abstract method.
    def click(self):    
        pass  
    def scroll(self):
        print("HP Scroll")

class HPNotebook(HP):
    def __init__(self):
        self()
    def click(self):
        print("HP Click")    
    def scroll(self):
        HP.scroll()

hp1=HPNotebook()
hp1.click()                  #the 2 level deep inherited function called by this instance
hp1.scroll()                 #the 1 level deep inherited function called by this instance
```

Comment: ```super()``` instead of ```self()``` in ```HPNotebook.__init__()```

Comment: Also, I don't think you can call `HP.scroll()`. You need to call `super().scroll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `self()` with `super()` on `HPNotebook.__init__` and replace `HP.scroll()` with `super().scroll()` on `HPNotebook.scroll`.

```py
class HPNotebook(HP):
    def __init__(self):
        super()
    def click(self):
        print("HP Click")    
    def scroll(self):
        super().scroll()
```

Also, check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-super-in-single-inheritance/) for better understanding about python inheritance.

Comment: Thanks you have all pointed out the issue.  And thanks for the link. Will read up more on Super and inheritance.